# Server-Client Chatting program

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, chat

i am creating server client chatting program through console.When i run the program , it just take inputs and inputs infinitely.

`Server code`

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Server {
    static final int PORT_NUM=4458;
    public static void main(String args []) {
     try {
            ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(PORT_NUM);
            Socket s=ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Server is listening...");
            String str1="";
            String str2="";

            DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    while(!str1.equals("STOP")) {
                        str1=din.readUTF();
                        System.out.println("Client says: "+str1);
                        str2=br.readLine();
                        dout.writeUTF(str2);
                        dout.flush();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Connection closed");
                    din.close();
                    dout.close();
                    s.close();
                    ss.close();
        }
     catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
     }
}
```

`Client code`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String args []) {
     try {
        Socket s=new Socket("localhost",4458);
        DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str1="";
        String str2="";
        while(!str1.equals("STOP")) {
            str1=br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(str1);
            dout.flush();
            str2=din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Client says: "+str2);
        }
        System.out.println("Connection closed");
        din.close();
        dout.close();
        s.close();
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
    }
}
```

One more doubt that is i run this program on eclipse IDE and There is only `one console`. As there is two different code so there must be `two consoles`  such that through one console i will give inputs behalf of server side and through another console i will give inputs behalf of client side. What should i do to do this?

I am unable to understand that where i got infinite loop. What should i do please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main methods and you can run them as two different programs in Eclipse.  Assuming that you have both open in an Eclipse, you can right click in the server code and select run.  Then change window to the client and repeat.  The consoles will be tabbed in the console window at the bottom.

For the loop, remember to type "STOP" in capitals.  You could also make use of "equalsIgnoreCase()" so that both "STOP" and "stop" will work.

Answer (score 1):

As for the infinite loop, I can't seem to find out why it happens. I'm not totally familiar with Eclipse, but NetBeans has a feature that enables running a .java file with a main method by right clicking it and selecting Run File. Perhaps Eclipse has a similar feature? All the same, you can have two Eclipse projects and run them separately,then switch to the console you want to access. Better yet, you can code outside of your IDE then run you code using two command prompts: one for the server and one for the client. This way you will be able to see the messages in "real time".
The following code worked for me. I typed it outside of my IDE and executed my code (Server first) using the command prompt.
Server code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Server {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 12345;
        String stop = "STOP";
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Waiting for client connection..");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection received from " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            String message = "";
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            
            boolean closed = false;
            while (!closed){
                System.out.print("Enter message: ");
                message = scanner.nextLine();
                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase(stop)){
                    closed = true;
                    output.writeObject(stop);
                    System.out.println("Session ended.");
                }
                else{
                    output.writeObject(message);
                    System.out.println("Client typing...");
                    try {
                        message = (String) input.readObject();
                        System.out.println("Client says: " + message);
                        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase(stop)){
                            closed = true;
                        }
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                        //Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}
```

Client code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter server address: ");
        String address = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter server port: ");
        int port = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();//get rid of new line left by nextInt();
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected to server. Waiting for message");
            String message = "";
            String stop = "STOP";
            boolean closed = false;
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while (!closed){
                try {
                    System.out.println("Server typing...");
                    message = (String) input.readObject();
                    System.out.println("Server says: " + message);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase(stop)){
                    closed = true;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("Enter message: ");
                    message = scanner.nextLine();
                    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase(stop)){
                        closed = true;
                        output.writeObject(stop);
                        System.out.println("Session ended.");
                    }
                    else{
                        output.writeObject(message);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Session ended.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.